# How to connect a specific Bluetooth device and how to communicate with that device (Bluetooth chat)

Tags: android, bluetooth, profile

I'm new in Bluetooth
I want to connect an already paired Bluetooth device and communicate with that device.
For this I use the following code.But it's not properly working
The code Finds the device but can't connect with that device.How to correct my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.util.Set;
 import java.util.UUID;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
   TextView myLabel;
   EditText myTextbox;
   BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
   BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
   BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
   OutputStream mmOutputStream;
   InputStream mmInputStream;
   Thread workerThread;
   byte[] readBuffer;
   int readBufferPosition;
   int counter;
   volatile boolean stopWorker;
   private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000110E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open);
    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    Button closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
    myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
    myTextbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
    }

    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
    }
    //Open Button
    openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {
                findBT();
                openBT();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });

    //Send Button
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {
                sendData();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });

    //Close button
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {
                closeBT();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });
}

void findBT()
{

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            if(device.getName().equals("BTdevice"))//name of the BT Device I want to connet
            {
                mmDevice = device;
                myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
                break;

            }
        }
    }

}

void openBT() throws IOException
{
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    mmSocket.connect();

    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

    beginListenForData();

    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
}

void beginListenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
            {
                try
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        myLabel.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
  }

   void sendData() throws IOException
   {
     String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
     msg += "\n";
     mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
     myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
   }

   void closeBT() throws IOException
   {
     stopWorker = true;
     mmOutputStream.close();
     mmInputStream.close();
     mmSocket.close();
     myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
   }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:ignore="TextFields,HardcodedText" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type here:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/label"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/open"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/entry"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:text="Open" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/open"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/open"
    android:text="Send" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/send"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="Close"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.tosil.myapplication">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

 <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

And also I would like to Know about which Bluetooth profile is used in this code and where it is mentioned.

Comment: What does " it's not properly working" mean? What is the error? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: This code finds the bluetooth device but failed to connect.

Comment: What is the exception? Please add your stacktrace.

Comment: I would suggest you to implement at least some logging, when an exception is thrown. Currently you  have it fail-silent: `catch (IOException ex) { }`. Just print out the exception: `catch (IOException ex) { Log.e(TAG, "Exception", ex); }`